# can i merge those 2 queries in one query

Tags: php, pdo

hello can i merge those 2 queries in one query my first query get the number of articles in database and second query get the sum of all visits of all article whats the best method to make it one query

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM stories');
$story_count = $stmt->rowCount();

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT sum(visits) FROM stories");
$total_visits = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT COUNT(*) as total_cnt,
                   SUM(visits) as total_visits FROM stories');
```

then excute your query,you will get result from "total_cnt" and "total_visits"

Comment: could you please write the full code coz i dont know how to use the row name with this $stmt->rowCount()

Comment: Thanks so much i got this error " Call to undefined method PDOStatement::result() "

Comment: Another error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LOGICAL_OR

Comment: not work iam sorry but +1 coz i got some tips and information from you Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, SUM(visits) as total_visits FROM stories;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Story.*, COUNT(*) as total, SUM(Story.visits) as total_visits FROM stories AS Story;
```

If you want to get other fields along with `SUM` and `COUNT` use `.*`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes try this:

```
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT count(*),sum(visits) FROM stories');
$result = $stmt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$story_count = $result[0];
$total_visits = $result[1];
```